# Setting up a node on a VM

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have my selenium all configured but seem to be having issues getting it to launch the browser on my windows VM. I think it's because I haven't haven't included the correct path to the driver. Currently it stands as...

```
java -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -port 1001 -hub http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:4444/grid/register
```

After reading online I assumed it's cause I'm missing the following...

```
-Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe"
```

I've tried various different ways to include this path into the above statement but keep getting 'poorly formatted Java property setting (I expect to see '=') -Dwebdriver: Usage: java -jar selenium-server.jar [-interactive] [options]'

if anyone could show me the correct format I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean setting up a Grid Hub+Node  or do you mean setting up a Node separate from the Grid Hub?

Comment: I have the hub already running it's just the node I want to get up and running now. Preferably combining the two statements above together. I set up the hub by running 'java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub' @djangofan

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver), you can use a system property:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe")
```

Of course this path would have be the correct on the remote machine!

If you use Maven for your builds, then the [Selenium binary downloader](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/08/introducing-the-driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin-for-selenium/) might interest you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running the node and having the node load a .json config file that looks something like this.

```
{
    "capabilities":
    [
        {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "acceptSslCerts": true,
            "javascriptEnabled": true,
            "takesScreenshot": false,
            "firefox_profile": "",
            "browser-version": "31",  
            "platform": "WINDOWS",                     
            "maxInstances": 5
        },
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "maxInstances": 5,
            "platform": "WINDOWS"
        },
        {
            "browserName": "internetExplorer",
            "maxInstances": 1,
            "platform": "WINDOWS"
        }
    ],
    "configuration":
    {
        "_comment" : "This is configuration for the grid node 1.",
        "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
        "timeout": 30000,
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "port": 5555,
        "host": ip,
        "Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe": "",
        "Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe": "",
        "register": true,
        "hubPort": 4444,
        "maxSessions": 5
    }
}
```